# How to set up a static/persistent ARP entry with OpenWRT 14.07, Barrier Breaker?

Tags: arp, openwrt, wake-on-lan

The title say it all, but here is the long version:

I am trying to setup a way for my home server to automatically turn on using WakeOnLan, when a client tries to access it. My idea is that the router (OpenWRT 14.07, Barrier Breaker) monitors any connection attempts to the host I want to wake up using `iptables` and in the case it registers such an event it sends the magic packet to wake the host. After lots of trying and help on SF, I have gotten iptables to work for the bridged device and thus local network ([see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/698847/iptables-on-openwrt-router-logging-connections-to-a-host-from-clients-on-the-sa)).

Unfortunately I now ran into the problem that, if the host is turned off, no ARP entry exists for it and thus *local* clients will not send any packets, when they cannot resolve the IP (if I have understood the problem correctly). For external clients accessing from the internet it works.

If I understand correctly, the solution should be to create a static ARP entry, so that the router will respond to any requests and then the clients will send their packet. Following [this](http://mtamsky.blogspot.de/2011/11/openwrt-and-wake-on-lan-wol-how-to-make.html) I have tried using the `ip neigh add 192.168.1.20 lladdr 00:de:ad:be:ef:00  nud permanent   dev br-lan` and running `arp` I see an entry for the server, but it still does not work.

I have confirmed, that when the server is turned on or was recently turned off (a few minutes prior), the clients *do* send packets, which are logged by `iptables`.

So the questions are:

1) What am I doing wrong?

2) How do I achieve a static/persistent ARP entry on the?

Comment: Be sure that the host you are adding the entry for has a static IP defined on that host (dont use DHCP). I had issues with DHCP interfering with static arp entries on OpenWRT.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use

```
ip neighbor replace 192.168.0.1 lladdr 11:22:33:44:55:66 nud permanent dev eth0
```

or if not requested already

```
ip neighbor add 192.168.0.1 lladdr 11:22:33:44:55:66 nud permanent dev eth0
```

To set the IP address to the MAC address.

Comment: You need `ip-full` package installed for these commands to work.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to have static ARP entries is to setup an external file, usually called /etc/ethers, with the format:

```
   00:11:22:33:44:55 192.168.1.2
   aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff 192.168.1.3
```

and so on, then to add the following line

```
   post-up arp -f /etc/ethers
```

(I do not know the *iproute2* equivalent of *arp -f*, but this command stil lworks on kernel 14.04) In the stanza for the *br-lan* interface in teh file */etc/network/interfaces*.

As to why your command; I do not know, it looks ok to me. What is the name of your bridged interface? In your example it is *br-lan*, you should have changed as per your needs.

Comment: Ok. So I got a working `arp` command in OpenWRT by installing `opkg install net-tools-arp`. When I now use `arp -s 192.168.1.20 00:11:22:33:44:55 -i br-lan`, it shows up in the arp table as: `192.168.1.20  ether  00:11:22:33:44:55  CM  br-lan`. So I would expect it to work, but is still does not. Running `sudo arpsend -D -e 192.168.1.20 wlan0` on my laptop, it just hangs and does not give back anything.

Comment: Furthermore, I couldn't find the post-up script, but when editing `/etc/ethers`, I found this for the boot-up in the logs: `Mon Jun 15 21:11:49 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1395]: read /etc/ethers - 1 addresses`. So Is there anything else I can try? Any suggestions for debugging/testing this? Thanks for your help so far BTW!

Comment: Oh. And with regards to the device: The bridge device is called `br-lan`, so that should be good.

Comment: @packoman I made a small mistake in my answer,now corrected, about the file where to put that line. Pls re-read my answer. Sorry about that.